# This algorithm computes the product of a & b, however I do not quite understand why this is the case. Could anyone explain it to me please?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

```
public static int mystery(int a, int b)
{
 if (b == 0) return 0;
 if (b % 2 == 0) return mystery(a+a, b/2);
 return mystery(a+a, b/2) + a;
}
```

I got this question out of Robert Sedgewick's Algorithms textbook. Question 1.1.14. This algorithm works for positive integers. However I'm unable to figure out why it's an implementation of multiplication.

Comment: Read about recursion, then write down on paper the result of each line of code using small input values such as 2 and 4.  After you understand it on paper, then actually run the code, stepping through the code with a couple small input values such as 2 and 4.  Watch the variables change, and the call stack as the recursion progresses.

Comment: Because `a * b = 2a * b/2`

Comment: In addition to what @Eritrean said, recall that multiplication can be seen as repeated addition.

Comment: It'a recursion, so prove it by induction. If b=0 then clearly mystery(a,b) = 0 = a*b. Now assuming mystery(a, k) returns a * k for all 0<=k < b. There are only 2 cases to prove, b is odd and b is even. HINT: when b is odd, java's `b/2` is not the same as the mathematical fraction b/2. You must also show that the algorithm terminates.

Comment: It's a recursive implementation of the shift-and-add algorithm for multiplication.

Comment: Got it, thank you everyone for your input :D